# Removing milliseconds using datediff

Tags: sql, datediff, milliseconds

The query is returning milliseconds which I want to remove

```
SELECT FOLIO_NUMBER, TERMINAL_NAME, ORDER_ENTRY_TIME, START_LOAD_TIME, END_LOAD_TIME,
       datediff(mi, ORDER_ENTRY_TIME, START_LOAD_TIME) AS STAGING_MINUTES,
       datediff(mi, START_LOAD_TIME, END_LOAD_TIME) AS LOADING_MINUTES,
       datediff(mi, ORDER_ENTRY_TIME, END_LOAD_TIME) AS TERMINAL_MINUTES   
FROM ORDERS  
JOIN TERMINAL_OWNER ON ORDERS.LOADING_TERMINAL_ID = TERMINAL_OWNER.TERMINAL_ID
WHERE TERMINAL_ID = '1913' AND FOLIO_NUMBER >= '20190101' AND FOLIO_NUMBER <= '20190201'
ORDER BY FOLIO_NUMBER ASC
```

Comment: Can anyone assist me?

Comment: Are you sure you're using `mi` and not `ms`?

Comment: Please tag your dbms (I suppose Sql Server)

Comment: mi = minutes; ms = milliseconds. See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017